# unordered_map hash function and operator==

Tags: stl, unordered-map

I created an unordered_map with class as a key and overloaded the hashing function. When I use unordered_map::find function, it doesn't enter the equality function (operator ==) instead it uses the hashing function in order to find the corresponding value to the key passed to unordered_map::find. I tried to print every time "==" operator is called and I noticed that neither count nor find use "==", but the hashing function instead.

What am I missing here?
What I wanted to do is to define a key which holds an unordered_map and a single value. Two keys are considered equal if the single value is in the unordered_map;

Something like this:

```
struct key_t{
    int single_val;
    unordered_map multi_val;
}

bool operator==(const key_t& src1, const key_t& src2) {
   return (src1.multi_val.count(src2.single_val) != 0);
}
```

This is what I did:

```
unordered_map<fixed_attribute_t, vector<unsigned int>, fixed_attribute_t::hash_t> fixedAttributeMap;
```

I defined an == operator as follows:

```
bool operator==(const fixed_attribute_t& fixedAttribute1, const fixed_attribute_t& fixedAttribute2) {
// case: multiple ports

if (fixedAttribute2.index != fixedAttribute1.index) {
    return false;
}

if (fixedAttribute1.portsMap != NULL) {
    return (fixedAttribute1.portsMap->count(fixedAttribute2.value) != 0);
}

if (fixedAttribute1.portRangeEnd != -1) {
    return ((fixedAttribute2.value <= fixedAttribute1.portRangeEnd && fixedAttribute2.value >= fixedAttribute1.portRangeStart
            && fixedAttribute1.isPortAttr == true));
}
return (fixedAttribute1.value == fixedAttribute2.value);
```

}

The hash function implementation:

```
class hash_t {
    std::hash<int> stdHash;

public:

    size_t operator()(const fixed_attribute_t& fixedAttribute) const {
        int portNum;
        if (fixedAttribute.portsMap != NULL) {
            auto it = fixedAttribute.portsMap->begin();
            portNum = it->first;
        }
        return stdHash(fixedAttribute.value ^ portNum);
    }
};
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: What's a `fixed_attribute_t`?  I don't see a definition here.  Best if you post a complete program that people can try.

Comment: Lots of problems. **(1)** Your `operator==` doesn't appear to define a valid equality comparison. For one thing, it's asymmetric - it's possible to have `a == b` but `!(b == a)`. **(2)** Your hash function uses an uninitialized variable `portNum` when `fixedAttribute.portsMap == NULL` **(3)** It is a requirement of `std::unordered_map` that two elements that compare equal have the same hash. Your implementation violates this invariant.

Comment: A simplified example appears to [work as expected](http://rextester.com/NQYY6729). My guess is, the map simply never finds an element with the same hash - it never calls `operator==` because it has nothing to compare with. Which, in turns, is likely caused by the fact that your hash function essentially produces random garbage.